# Change page URL view in a browser field

Tags: html

When I ask for some page on my website I usually do something like this:

```
<a href="/views/somepage.html">Click here</a>
```

And when I go to this page the URL that I see in my browser URL field at the top shows:

```
mywebsite.com/views/somepage.html
```

It doesn't look very professional though. How can I change the URL that is seen in my browser field at the top?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to change anything on my webserver. Is there some simple html trick to do it simpler and faster?

Comment: *"I don't want to change anything on my webserver. Is there some simple html trick to do it simpler and faster?"* – No. If you want your official URL to be, say, `mywebsite.com/somepage`, then your web server will need to respond with the appropriate page when you request `/somepage` from it. That is a matter of web server configuration.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks :D